# How to run my Crystal Report in Crystal Report runtime 13.2.469

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using *Visual Studio 2015* to develop a small application. That application needs *Crystal Report* runtime 13.0.22 to run the report. My client PC has already installed *Crystal Report* runtime 13.2.469 to load another application report.

But my report is not run through the installed *Crystal Report* runtime 13.2.469. When I install *Crystal Report* runtime 13.0.22, the previous version of *Crystal Report* runtime upgraded and my application report runs successfully, but that of another application report does not run.

How can I run my application report without installing my *Crystal Report* runtime 13.0.22?

I mean that I want to run my application report through *Crystal Report* runtime 13.2.469 which is already installed on that client PC.

Does anyone know how to help me?